# Create a "Products per city" site

Tags: product-attribute

I'm completely new to Magento but, I am a Drupal developer.  I'm currently looking into creating a site that sells products organized by their origin city.  I'd like your suggestions on how to organize the site.

Requirements:

- Easily search for products across cities
- Same product terms for products in all cities
- Filter products(product grids/lists, etc) by city

Should I create a store per city? Or Category per city?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you described it would be sufficient to create a product attribute "origin_city" and make it filterable. Then you will be able to filter by city in search results as well as in every category that has the "is anchor" setting

Comment: For starters, this is probably the best way to go. THX!

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is probably too broad as it is going to depend greatly on your business requirements.

You could set it up where each city is a category, nothing wrong with that as long as it meets your requirements. What if, however, you want to treat each city's store similar to how you would treat a Canadian/European/Asian multi-store setup? Categories would obviously not work in this scenario.

Chances are, no matter how you decide to set it up, you will get to a point where you won't be able to (easily) do what you thought you would be able to do. My advice is to start prototyping different setups to see where the requirement gaps are so that you can choose the path of least resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I think I'm going to have to experiment a bit until I find a good solution. If the site draws significant traffic and scaling is an issue, I'd actually be happy with that.